# Select query in row_to_json function

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, composite-types

For example ,
I use the following function to convert `rows` into `json` in `PostgreSQL 9.2`

```
select row_to_json(row(productid, product)) from gtab04;
```

and this will returns below results

```
row_to_json
---------------
{"f1":3029,"f2":"DIBIZIDE M TAB"}
{"f1":3026,"f2":"MELMET 1000 SR TAB"}
{"f1":2715,"f2":"GLUCORED FORTE"}
{"f1":3377,"f2":"AZINDICA 500 TAB"}
```

- unfortunately it loses the field names and replaces them with f1, f2, f3, etc.
- How can I get the actual field names or cast field name?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To work around this we must either create a row type and cast the row to that type or use a subquery. A subquery will typically be easier.

```
select row_to_json(t)
from (
   select productid, product from gtab04
) t
```

Answer (score 11):

If one wants to prevent a sub-query, `json_build_object()` might be a solution. It does not map the column name, but let's your set the JSON keys explicitly.

---

**Query**

```
SELECT json_build_object('productid', productid, 'product', product) FROM gtab04;

json_build_object                                
------------------
{"productid":3029,"product":"DIBIZIDE M TAB"}
{"productid":3026,"product":"MELMET 1000 SR TAB"}
{"productid":2715,"product":"GLUCORED FORTE"}  
{"productid":3377,"product":"AZINDICA 500 TAB"}
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the row() from your query.

```
select row_to_json(productid, product) from gtab04;
```

This will make sure row column names are maintained.